# MySQL complex join - Can't select multiple columns in second table

Tags: mysql, join

I can't figure out why I can't select multiple columns in the second table.  Here are my tables:

```
Computers:
----------
id, cond, type

Images:
-------
id, foreignid, name, width, height, def
```

Here is my select statement:

```
SELECT
    id, cond, type,
    (SELECT name, width, height FROM images WHERE foreignid = computers.id ORDER BY def DESC LIMIT 1) AS image
FROM computers
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
select c.id, c.cond, c.type, i.name, i.width, i.height from computers c
left join images i on i.foreignid=c.id
order by i.def desc limit 1
```

EDIT:
But the join clause depends on what exactely you want.
If you want all computers, have they images or not use

```
computers left join images
```

If you want all images, have they computers or not use

```
computers right join images
```

If you want only computers with images and images with computers use

```
computers inner join images
```

If you want all computers and all images use

```
computer outer join images
```

Comment: I want all computers and just one image, there default image (def column if its 1)

Comment: Then use the first statement of my post.

Comment: Thank you, I added on i.foreignid = c.id AND i.def > 0 and removed the limit statement to finish up the query. Stackoverflow FTW again.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT comp.id, comp.cond, comp.type, img.name, img.height, img.width FROM computers comp left join image img on img.foreignid = comp.id
```

Will return a computer, with its related image if that is what you are looking for.